# Prime numbers and multiplicative order

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Determine all prime numbers $p$ for which $ord_p(2)=6$ where $ord_p(2)$ is the multiplicative order of $2 \mod p$.

Comment: What did you try? Do you see why there are only a finite numbers of primes that are possible candidates?

Answer (score 1):

By definition, $\operatorname{ord}_p(2)=6$ if and only if $6$ is the smallest positive integer $n$ such that $$2^n\equiv1\pmod p.$$ A necessary condition for that is $$p|(2^6-1),$$ thus $p=3,7$. Now it's easy to see that $\operatorname{ord}_3(2)=2$ and $\operatorname{ord}_7(2)=3$. Thus there is no such prime $p$ that $\operatorname{ord}_p(2)=6$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

It must be that

$$2^6=64\equiv1\pmod p\;,\;\;\text{and also}\;\;2^k\rlap{\;\,/}\equiv1\pmod p\;\;\text{for all}\;\;1\le k<6$$

Also, what would you say $\;2^3\pmod p\;$ must be...?